# Javascript Donot allow on csv load more then 4 columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Iam trying to restrict the number of columns to be loaded on CSV upload my below code uploads displays the CSV data in a div but iam trying to restrict the columns to be loaded on a div say my below example of the csv shows there are 7 columns and i want to show only first 4 columns by skipping the first row that is heading.
My Basic Idea is to import later this data in to sq-lite data base using java script or j query

```
heading 1   heading 2   heading 3   heading 4   heading 5   heading 6   heading 7
column1     column2      column3     column4    column5      column6     column7
column1     column2      column3     column4    column5      column6     column7
column1     column2      column3     column4    column5      column6     column7
column1     column2      column3     column4    column5      column6     column7
column1     column2      column3     column4    column5      column6     column7
column1     column2      column3     column4    column5      column6     column7
column1     column2      column3     column4    column5      column6     column7
```

[Demo JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8fME/2391/)

HTML:

```
<input id = "csv" type = "file" /> 

<div id="result"></div>
```

JS:

```
 $('#csv').change(function(e) {
if ((window.FileReader) && (e.target.files != undefined)) {
  var reader = new FileReader(); 
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var lineSplit = e.target.result.split("\n").join("dassa");
    var commaSplit = lineSplit[0].split(",");
    var content = "";

      for(var j = 0; i < lineSplit.length; j++) {
    for(var i = 0; i < commaSplit.length; i++) {
      var temp = commaSplit[i];
        alert(commaSplit[i]);
      content = content + " " + temp;
    }
    }
    var fileContent = reader.result;
    $('#result').html(fileContent);
  };

  reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));    
}
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following code snippets

```js
$('#csv').change(function(e) {
  if ((window.FileReader) && (e.target.files != undefined)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {

      var lineSplit = e.target.result.split("\n");
      var content = [];

      for (var j = 1; j < lineSplit.length; j++) {
        var fourColumnsData = lineSplit[j].split(',').slice(0, 4).join(" ");

        content.push(fourColumnsData);

      }
      var fileContent = content.join("<br/>");
      $('#result').html(fileContent);

    };

    reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="csv" type="file" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support i have a quick question if you dont mind can i?

Comment: i have modified the code as per my need am trying to create a  sql query so `column1','column2','column3','column4'),
column1','column2','column3','column4'),
column1','column2','column3','column4'),
column1','column2','column3','column4'),` after i made a modification am getting the out put as above but i need that some thing like this`('column1','column2','column3','column4'),
('column1','column2','column3','column4'),
('column1','column2','column3','column4'),
('column1','column2','column3','column4');`

Comment: @Shaik please update your jsfiddle or create a new question as it will be easier for me to check your working code?

Comment: done i have posted a new question greate to see some one helping alot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719970/convert-a-fetched-data-in-div-from-excel-to-a-query

Answer (score 0):

You can start your for loop with value of 1 for rows. so first row is skipped and you can check for columns length.

If your columns length is 7 , you can check condition like columnsLength <= 4 in for loop.