# Convert a Fetched data in div from excel to a query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The below code fetches data from a `csv` and presents in to a `div` as a `text` but am trying to convert that in to a `query` on fetch excel import and print then as a `query`

Current output when the data is imported from the excel
Example:

```
column1','column2','column3','column4')
column1','column2','column3','column4')
column1','column2','column3','column4')
column1','column2','column3','column4')
column1','column2','column3','column4')
```

Expected output

```
 ('column1','column2','column3','column4'),
('column1','column2','column3','column4'),
('column1','column2','column3','column4'),
('column1','column2','column3','column4'),
('column1','column2','column3','column4');
```

[JS fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W8fME/2455/)

HTML:

```
<input id = "csv" type = "file" /> 

<div id="result"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#csv').change(function(e) {

  if ((window.FileReader) && (e.target.files != undefined)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {

      var lineSplit = e.target.result.split("\n");
      var content = [];

      for (var j = 1; j < lineSplit.length; j++) {
        var fourColumnsData = lineSplit[j].split(',').slice(0, 4).join("','");

        content.push(fourColumnsData);

      }
      var fileContent = content.join("')<br/>");
      $('#result').html(fileContent);

    };

    reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```js
$('#csv').change(function(e) {

  if ((window.FileReader) && (e.target.files != undefined)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {

      var lineSplit = e.target.result.split("\n");
      var content = [];

      for (var j = 1; j < lineSplit.length; j++) {
        if (lineSplit[j].trim().length > 0) {
          var fourColumnsData = "('" + lineSplit[j].split(',').slice(0, 4).join("','") + "')";

          content.push(fourColumnsData);
        }
      }
      var fileContent = content.join(",");
      $('#result').html(fileContent);

    };

    reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="csv" type="file" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: superb  but at last infect there is no row blank but still a blank data is added `('column1','column1','column1','column1'),('column2','column2','column2','column2'),('column3','column3','column3','column3'),('column4','column4','column4','column4'),('column5','column5','column5','column5'),('column6','column6','column6','column6'),('column7','column7','column7','column7'),('column10','column10','column10','column10'),('column11','column11','column11','column11'),('')` If there is any blank cell found on the row can u skip that row?

Comment: but one issue was not solved it dosent skips if the row cell lefts blank

Comment: @Shaik it is skipping blank rows for me.